# How much time is the shuttle run from BWI airport to BWI Amtrak station?

Tags: usa, buses, train-stations, amtrak, bwi

There is an Amtrak station nearby to Baltimore-Washington International Airport (both are code BWI in respective travel systems).  There is a 2.1 mile, 41 minute estimated walk duration open-to-weather footpath between these transit nodes; they are not exactly co-located.  The [BWI webpage](https://www.bwiairport.com/to-from-bwi/transportation/transit/amtrak) only states the periodicity of a shuttle (1 per 10 minutes in the midday) not the duration of the shuttle leg.

> BWI Marshall Airport offers free, frequent, and convenient shuttle service between the MARC/Amtrak station and the BWI Marshall Airport terminal. Shuttle Service operates 24 hours a day, 365 days a year. Shuttles run approximately every 10 minutes, except between the hours of 1:00 a.m. and 5:00 a.m. when service operates every 25 minutes.

Comment: Why do you think that is is not possible to walk? Google Maps finds what seems to be a very useable route for walking.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo After a trip back to google maps I have edited the walking detail

Comment: The BWI page you link has contact information for BWI Customer Service at the bottom, both telephone and email. Have you asked them? Remember too that trains in the US sometimes run at long intervals; so missing one and having to wait for the next one might be a significant disruption in your day. I'd suggest you build some extra time into your schedule.

Comment: The MARC timetable for BWI to Union station is https://www.mta.maryland.gov/schedule/timetable/marc-penn - between 6AM and 6PM the trains run pretty frequently. After that... Also check the Amtrak schedule - a bit pricier but also faster.

Comment: We can guess from the midnight service that it takes the bus <25 minutes to do a round trip, including a margin for  bathroom break for the driver.

Comment: We can guess from the midnight service that it takes the bus <25 minutes (traffic not included)  to do a round trip, including a margin for  bathroom break for the driver.

Comment: It's not a particularly pedestrian-friendly walk, although there is a sidewalk, it's mostly alongside busy roads and parking lots. The shuttle is free, runs frequently, and offers door-to-door service between the Amtrak/MARC station and the terminal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you use Google maps to mark the route from the airport to the Amtrak station, and then select the public transport option (similar to how you used the walking option to identify your 2.1 mile walk), Google will tell you that the shuttle takes 12 minutes and makes 5 stops.

Note that the 14 minutes mentioned on the map itself includes walking to/from the shuttle from where I identified the start/end points

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Although the Google info provided in @PeterM's answer is mostly correct, I've ridden that shuttle multiple times in both directions, between BWI Airport and BWI train station, and the only "multiple" stops are the couple of stops it makes at the airport terminal itself.  Once it leaves the terminal, it goes directly to the train station (or leaving the train station, it goes directly to the airport).  Though be watchful of the stops at the airport side, as not all of them are open all of the time.  Although the information says they run every 10 minutes, that can fluctuate due to road traffic, passenger loading, etc.  They can sometimes bunch up, where a couple busses come in short order, then there's a 15+ minute wait for the next one.

Just make sure to look for the proper bus, as there are several independent bus routes at BWI airport, one for the train station, one for the car rental facility, one for long term parking, and there could be another as well that I'm not remembering.

Comment: I haven't taken the shuttle but I have driven to BWI many times, including a few weeks ago. The multiple stops are likely referring to different airlines/sections of the terminal - all in one big semicircle.

Comment: I can come from a different angle, as my one visit to BWI, I did transfer from airport to train (to head to DC), I walked because I didn't know about the shuttle... and I saw them going by (among the others), making very limited stops (basically as manassehkatz indicates) and wished I'd taken it. But walking didn't take anything away from the day for me :-)  I do hazily seem to remember it however taking me a bit of time to figure out where I was suppose to be once at the station, so that may be something you want to factor in if indeed you're thinking about cutting a tight schedule.

Comment: Patterns may have changed recently (I haven't flown BWI since before COVID), but in my experience the shuttle definitely makes a stop at the Northrop Grumman parking lot. Unless you are flying during weekday rush hour, however, this does not add much to the time.